Dynamically create pydantic models from list of BaseModel(s)
I want to automate function creation for llms using pyndatic and instructor and I'm stuck at creating a dynamic result model from the created functions.
FunctionStorage = _FunctionStorage()

@FunctionStorage.store()
class PythonCmd(OpenAISchema):
    """runs a python snippet or script"""
    snippet: str = Field(description="python snippet to run")

    @computed_field
    def result(self) -> str:
        with open('r2ai_tmp.py', 'w') as f:
            return f.read()

ResultModel = ? # no idea how to properly do this

I've tried with
class _ResultModel(BaseModel):
    results: List[DataT]

ResultModel = _ResultModel(results=tool for tool in FunctionStorage.get_all())

But I'm getting _TypeError: unhashable type: 'ResultModel' when instructor tries to parse the openai response and use my model
